# Trigger.io: forge.prefs Variable Scope in a function

Tags: javascript, function, trigger.io, forge

We are having difficulty assigning a forge.prefs value to a variable, so that we can pass it on as a parameter.

This is a sample call:

```
forge.prefs.get('offset_val' function(offset1){
     offset = offset1; 
})
forge.prefs.get('id', function(val){
     uid = val;
})

load_my_car(uid,offset);
```

It is returning `undefined` and it is very inconvenient to call it in a nested prefs command.

Can someone help us regarding this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forge.prefs.get()` is probably an asynchronous function call, which means that its callback is executed somewhat delayed. In your example `load_my_car()` is executed before the two callbacks are fired, so the variables are still undefined.

You have to make sure that the callbacks are fired before calling `load_my_car()`, try this:

```
forge.prefs.get('offset_val' function(offset1){
  forge.prefs.get('id', function(val){
    load_my_car(val,offset1);
  }); 
});
```

If you really don't want to have two nested `forge.prefs.get()` you'd need to check which callback finishes first and then only call `load_my_car()` after the second finished.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry I forgot. Thanks!